# Access Query to return top 5 and sum all others

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've found various examples of [answers](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/409165cf-04ad-4d30-a345-e14688dd176a/query-to-return-top-n-with-other-grouping-for-all-remaining-rows?forum=transactsql) to [questions](http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/477487-sql-how-display-top-5-then-sum-rest) very [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517989/select-top-all-but-10-from-in-microsoft-access/518008#518008) to mine. For some reason I can not get my query to work though.

What am I doing wrong?

**I want to have the top 5 results returned with all other rows shown in the last row as "others".**

Here is my SQL Syntax:

```
SELECT TOP 5 tbl_MopoRohdaten.rating_clir, Sum(tbl_MopoRohdaten.c2_eop_weight) AS SumOfc2_eop_weight
FROM tbl_MopoRohdaten
WHERE tbl_MopoRohdaten.rating_clir 
NOT IN 
    (EXISTS(SELECT TOP 5 tbl_MopoRohdaten.rating_clir, Sum(tbl_MopoRohdaten.c2_eop_weight) AS SumOfc2_eop_weight FROM  tbl_MopoRohdaten))
GROUP BY tbl_MopoRohdaten.rating_clir;
```

When I run it I get an error statement telling me:

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified
>   expression 'rating_clir' as part of an aggregate function.

**UPDATE:**

I've adjusted the code to reflect Balnian's input, but now Access (the entire application) simply shuts down and crashes whenever I try to run it!

```
SELECT TOP 5 tbl_MopoRohdaten.rating_clir, Sum(tbl_MopoRohdaten.c2_eop_weight) AS SumOfc2_eop_weight
FROM tbl_MopoRohdaten
WHERE tbl_MopoRohdaten.rating_clir 
NOT IN 
    (EXISTS(SELECT TOP 5 tbl_MopoRohdaten.rating_clir,Sum(tbl_MopoRohdaten.c2_eop_weight) AS SumOfc2_eop_weight 
FROM   tbl_MopoRohdaten GROUP BY y tbl_MopoRohdaten.rating_clir))
GROUP BY tbl_MopoRohdaten.rating_clir;
```

Answer (score 0):

The select in the exist part of you query is missing the `group by` that is mandatory since you have a SUM() and a normal column returned in your query

```
EXISTS(SELECT TOP 5 tbl_MopoRohdaten.rating_clir,
Sum(tbl_MopoRohdaten.c2_eop_weight) AS SumOfc2_eop_weight FROM 
tbl_MopoRohdaten)
```

should be (not tested)

```
EXISTS(SELECT TOP 5 tbl_MopoRohdaten.rating_clir,Sum(tbl_MopoRohdaten.c2_eop_weight) AS SumOfc2_eop_weight 
FROM   tbl_MopoRohdaten group by tbl_MopoRohdaten.rating_clir)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, when I run the query now with the updated statement, Access crashes on me. It simply shuts down. No error message for SQL. Any idea why this might happen? I added an updated to my original post